# How to count in a SQL list

Tags: mysql

I've made a table with the columns for a customer name and each activity they participate in. How can I can I count the activities for each name and display it? 
I've done;

```
SELECT Activity_Name, COUNT(*) AS 'Number_of_activities'
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Activity_Name;
```

which gives me each a table of each activity and how many participants in each activity but not each customer and their number of activities

Apologies for anything I've done wrong, only a couple months into coding and first time posting on stack...

Comment: I think you are going to have to explain your schema a little better than you have

Comment: It sounds like you just need to replace `Activity_Name` with whatever column you're using for customer (e.g. `Customer_Name`) in your query...

Comment: And I am thinking that the activities shoudl be in a seperate table for this to be sensibly designed

Comment: Literally just figured this out. Exactly what you said Zack, thanks!

Comment: @JetBlackT Don't forget to accept the answer from papazulu, which suggests the same thing. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering I don't know how your schema looks exactly, this query should be a nice representation of the idea how to do it:

```
SELECT customer_name, COUNT(*) AS 'Number_of_activities_per_customer'
FROM tablename
GROUP BY customer_name;
```

Comment: literally figured it out about a minute after I posted, thank you!